# TreeTableView but in columns?

Tags: javafx, treetableview

I am new to javafx and i have been working with TreetableView.
I was wonthering if there is something similar but that I could do the samething with columns that you can do with rows. I mean something that you could squash and expand similarly as with items containing subitems on the rows.

I have not been able to find something similar on the web.

Thanks in advance,
Eduardo

Comment: not supported by plain fx, not aware of third-party controls

Comment: The best solution would be to implement a custom skin for TreeTableView which displays the table in a different orientation.  That is not something I would at all recommend somebody new to JavaFX to attempt.  My advice is to come up with a different method of representing your data that can be based primarily on the existing functionality of the standard control and layout sets.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advise. I am new to javafx but I have a lot of experience in other object oriented languages. The problem that i have is that i would need the expandeable functionality on both: rows and columns.